# condition - a / no article

Tags: articles, zero-article

Why in some cases **condition** is used with an article and in some cases with no article?
For example:

> Considering its age, this house is in excellent condition.
>
> He was in a terrible condition and had drunk far too much whiskey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking the indefinite article could be present or absent in both the specified examples. But idiomatically we're more likely to include the article in the *second* case.

This is because explicitly specifying *in **a** condition* more strongly implies that there are ***other*** conditions - which *could* have applied, but don't *(in the specific case mentioned).*

Something like the state of repair of a *house* is a relatively ***static*** "condition", so it would often be reasonable to completely ignore alternative conditions. But the state of being inebriated after drinking too much is relatively ***transient***, so including the article there more explicitly singles out *that* state from the condition he was in before he started drinking, and after he sobered up.

---

Also note that in contexts like *He is in condition*, it's idiomatically established that we mean ***fit, healthy*** state/condition. We wouldn't normally say *He is in **a** condition*, because the idiomatic standard there is *He is in **a state*** - where it's assumed we mean *He is in a **bad, confused** state/condition*.

We *always* include the article with ***state*** in such constructions, but it's optional with ***condition***.